# Create variable reporting period : ' 2019 - 2020'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a automated variable showing the "reporting Period' in the format of last year - this year like : 2019 - 2020

```
SELECT 
     (DATEPART(yyyy, [SubmissionDate] )-1) - (DATEPART(yyyy, [SubmissionDate])) as Reporting_Period
from x
```

---

```
(DATEPART(yyyy, [SubmissionDate] )-1) : is 2019 works
(DATEPART(yyyy, [SubmissionDate]))    : is 2020 works
```

But how can I write a static '-'  (as in 2019 - 2020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CONCAT function like below

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT((DATEPART(yyyy, [SubmissionDate] )-1),'-', (DATEPART(yyyy, [SubmissionDate]))) as Reporting_Period
from x
```